# getting a variable from a different thread android java

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, runnable

I'm getting the error : android.os.networkonmainthreadexception. I found out, that that happens because i have to put internet requests on a thread other than main. I've searched for ways to put it on a seperate thread, and used this one, since i can understand it fairly well:

```
public void use() throws Exception
{
    int a;
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                //do something
        a=32;
        //do smthn else
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    thread.start();
int b= a;
}
```

I make a new thread and put the network layer in it. The problem is, i can't get variables out of it. when i do like int b= a; as seen in the code it says : Variable (int a) is accesed from within inner class, needs to be declared final(int b). How can i get the int a outside from the variable in a easy way?

All help is much appreciated :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either a [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html) or an [EventBus](https://github.com/square/otto) to report results from a worker thread back to the main/ui thread.

N.B: That depends on the context, but creating your own "Runnable" threads might not be the best way to thread on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a suggestion, make your class implement `Runnable` like this:

```
public class MyClass implements Runnable
{
    int a;

    public void use()
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            //do something
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, variable 'a' is visible both inside your `Thread` and in you functions. At the end of `run()` you can call a function that sets `b = a;` or something like that, in which case b should be defined together with a on top, but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, so you can be the judge.

Answer (score 0):

I saw an issue in your code. That is when you assign b = a, maybe the thread doesn't finish yet, so variable b get the wrong value. To solve problem, I think you could run whole use() method in a separate thread.

In case you still want to just run some line of them, you could try this sample:

```
class Wrapper {
    // Use wrapper for change the value of final primary variable
    int a;
}

public void use() {
    final Wrapper a = new Wrapper();
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            a.a = 120;
        }
    });
    t.start();

    // Block current thread until t finish
    // So make sure b get the right value
    try {
        t.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int b = a.a;
}
```